# JSON / REST API standard for "no data"

Tags: json, rest, jsonschema

Is one of the two approaches preferred when designing data model/API?

**Approach 1**: element is required but null is an accepted type

Schema

```
{
    "properties": {
        "prop1": {
            "type": string"
        },
        "prop2": {
            "type": ["null", "string"]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "prop1",
        "prop2"
    ]
}
```

Valid data

```
{
    "prop1": "test",
    "prop2": null
}
```

Invalid data

```
{
    "prop1": "test"
}
```

**Approach 2**: element is not required and only accepted as string

Schema

```
{
    "properties": {
        "prop1": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "prop2": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "prop1"
    ]
}
```

Valid data

```
{
    "prop1": "test"
}
```

Invalid data

```
{
    "prop1": "test",
    "prop2": null
}
```

Are there any (dis)advantages of one approach over the other?

Comment: Approach 2 is simpler and much clearer. I cannot see any benefit of approach 1. In fact I'm not convinced spproach 1 would even work....